# Equation without parantheses

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some exercises on KhanAcademy and I saw an equation something like this:

$y=-x^2$

If $x$ is equal to $-4$, the equation becomes:

$y=--4^2$

How do I calculate this equation?

I thought of these options:

$y=-(-4)^2 = -(16) = -16$

$y=(--4)^2 = (4)^2 = 16$

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: the first way is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is that $y=-x^2$ should be read as $y=-(x^2)$  Then if you want to substitute $-4$ for $x$, you get $y=-((-4)^2)$.  The minus sign that comes with the $x$ needs to get squared, but not the one that came with the initial equation.

Answer (score 2):

$y=-x^2$

If $x=-4$, then $y=-(-4)^2=-16$

Comment: Hi Adi. Nice to see you while it is snowing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your first way is correct.

Think of $y = -x^2$ as $y = -(x^2)$.

Comment: When I used to teach I would tell students to think of $y = -x^2$ as $y = -1 \cdot x \cdot x$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You could also think of it as $-1*x^2$ and apply order of operations, but hey, you're the one who actually taught students this stuff.

Comment: What I like about $-1 \cdot x \cdot x$ is that it allows you to remind students lots of things, such as the coefficient is the number $-1$ and squaring means multiply by itself. You also don't have to create extra parentheses that weren't there to begin with, and which you'd only know were there if you already knew the correct interpretation. But the order of operations issue is also useful, and I've used it as well in viewing $-x^2$ as $-1 \cdot x^2$ as you suggested.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $-x$ as the unique solution to the equation $x+y=0$, solving for $y$. Then, we want to solve $4^2+y = 0\Rightarrow 16+y=0\Rightarrow y=-16$. Of course from then on just remember that exponentiating goes first, but this is a kind of justification.

In fact, this is *the* definition of $-x$.